# Typescript-style union type to define map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I would like to create a `std::map` which only allows specific keys. In Typescript I would do something along the lines of

```js
type AllowedKeys = "foo" | "bar" | "baz";
const map: Record<AllowedKeys,any> = {
  foo: "hello",
  bar: "world",
  baz: "goog",
};
```

Can something similar be done in c++?

Comment: The only restriction you can set is on types. Use an enum class as key.

Comment: Seems like enum class is what I was looking for but didn't have the fantasy to search for. Cheers